# How to parse JSON data without model class in Flutter and get single value?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing

```json
{
  "result": "success",
  "base_code": "AFN",
  "rates": {
    "USD": 1,
    "AED": 3.6725,
    "AFN": 89.015484,
    "ALL": 108.195795
  }
}
```

In Kotlin we parse like that...

```kotlin
val jsonObj = JSONObject("${result.body()}")
val rate = jsonObj.get("rates").get("USD")
```

But I want to do it in Flutter with Dart. How can I achieve this? Keep in mind that I want to do it without model class. I need just one value from the whole JSON response.

I have tried this. But it's not working.

```dart
void getCurrenciesRatesFromServer() {
  repository.getCurrenciesRates(selectedFromCountryCode).then((value) async {
    var response = json.decode(value);
    log("${response['result']['USD']}");
  }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
    log("$error");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing in correct way but you're trying to access the value which is not there.

You can try following thing:

```dart
void getCurrenciesRatesFromServer() {
  repository.getCurrenciesRates(selectedFromCountryCode).then((value) async {
    var response = json.decode(value);
    log("${response['result']}"); //This will display success
    log("${response['rates']['USD']}"); // This will give you 1
  }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
    log("$error");
  });
}
```

Comment: No that's not the issue. It's giving me this error....
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: Look closely, you're doing wrong there `log("${response['result']['USD']}");` . You must get the data with `rates` not `result` as @Rohan Jariwala did above.

Comment: You’re getting that error because you’re trying to use Map like this response[result][USD]. It will throw the error because the response[result] is string and you cannot do String[something]. You can do with response[rates][USD] as response[rates] is Map type value.